# mate-screenshot 1.26.0 suddenly producing corrupt screenshots?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop, corruption, screenshot

Looking for first steps to diagnose this strange change in behavior: If I launch mate-screenshot and choose Copy to Clipboard, **no program will paste the image**, including:

1. The StackExchange form I'm typing this into—it shows up as a "broken image" icon.
2. GIMP (start, then hit Ctrl+Shift+V to "paste as new image")—shows a loading spinner cursor forever.
3. Slack, which pops up with "File unsupported ... Sorry, image.png is a type of file not supported by Slack ... Try uploading a .zip version of this file instead."

I've regularly used mate-screenshot for months now **in all of these contexts** without ever having this happen, until last week some time.  And [there haven't been any updates lately](https://tracker.debian.org/pkg/mate-utils) to the package it comes in.  The behavior persists between cold boots.

I'm using Linux Mint 20.3 Una 64-bit.  This happens whether I run mate-screenshot plain or with the `--area` parameter.

Another screen-grab util, [Collabshot](https://www.collabshot.com/), still works fine, but I sometimes prefer mate-screenshot.  What could have broken it?

Answer (score 0):

The mystery deepens.  After finally writing this up, I tried pressing <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> (which is a predefined shortcut to take a screenshot of just the active window), and after that, mate-screenshot (from the command line, with or without `--area`, and from a custom keyboard shortcut defined with `--area`) worked fine.  Even after a cold boot, my custom shortcut continues to work (without first doing an <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd>), producing pasteable screenshots.

**TL;DR: somehow a single <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>PrintScreen</kbd> keypress fixed this behavior permanently...**

Comment: Just had this problem happen again—thought it might be related to switching my GPU to performance mode.  Still, this fix did the trick!

Comment: Lately I also had to _copy_ said alt+prtscn'd screenshot before it fixed subsequent shots.